# JMeter - CSS/JQuery Extractor: what empty Render implementation means?

Tags: jmeter

In [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Render you can choose CSS/Jquery Implementation,

CSS/Jquery Implementation can be empty (third option)

[image]

Why do we need such option? is that used if we can add our own implementation? is it simply a bug (usually there's an edit option) ?

- in JMeter code `HtmlExtractor` uses JSoup as default, but it is not shown in UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blank means : "No override, use default default implementation defined by property:

> htmlParser.className=org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.JsoupBasedHtmlParser

If you set JSOUP or JODD, it means you override this for a particular element.

It is the same convention as for HTTP Request